# jQuery, div with fixed height and smallest possible width

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hejsa!

I can't quite get this example to work.

http://aspitkbh.dk/lise/intro11/

The boxes are supposed to be the smallest possible width. (To not break the page while I wait for answer, I have set the width to auto there. Below is the code I thought would work.)

EDIT: I expect when the width is "too little", that the box will grow too high. Then I want to reduce the height until it is 170. The box will be too high or too wide because there's "too much" text in it.

```
<div class="myBoxExercise box1">Se en demo.
<button type="button" class="myButton" onclick="colorMe(this)">OK</button>
</div>
<div class="noMoreBox"></div>
<h3>Opgave 2</h3>
<div class="myBoxExercise box1">Du bliver.
<button type="button" class="myButton" onclick="colorMe(this)">OK</button>
</div>

.myBoxExercise {
    height: 170px;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}


// JavaScript Document
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15227350/full-height-content-with-the-smallest-possible-width
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "div.myBoxExercise" ).each(function( index ) {
        // The 160 = 170-2*5 is because you have to subtract the container padding and the element's own padding
        // Or not?
        while($(this).height() > 190) {
            currentWidth = $(this).width();
            $(this).width(currentWidth + 1);    
        }
        console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).width() );
    });
});
```

Comment: Your while loop looks to be never ending.

Comment: The while loop will never hit because $(this).height() is 170px as you set it in your CSS. 170 is not greater than 190.  With that being said, I'm not entirely clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to solve it.

I changed the css to this:

```
.myBoxExercise {
    width: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

And ended with this js:

```
$( "div.myBoxExercise" ).each(function( index ) {
    while($(this).height() > 170) {
        currentWidth = $(this).width();
        $(this).width(currentWidth + 1);    
    }
    $(this).height(170);
    if ($(this).width() < 150) {
        $(this).width(150);
    }
});
```

It works pretty much how I wanted it to now. The comments helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to that your div.myBoxExercise height should be not greater than 170 and its width should be not greater than 150... why not you are trying css max-height and max-width property.

```
 div.myBoxExercise{max-height:170px;max-width:150px;}
```

And if you are tying something else, please ignore this.